# Datos no se guardan en el array de la session de PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session

apenas voy empezando en esto, hace poco me pusieron un proyecto escolar que va de una tienda online, estoy usando PHP y siguiendo un tutorial de YT, mi problema es al momento de hacer el carrito de compras, cuando se guarda un producto en el carrito se supone que debería guardarme las ID de los productos en la array de la session de PHP pero no lo hace.

Arriba está como se supone que debería quedar el arreglo y abajo es como me está quedando a mi [image]

```
    <?php

require '../config/config.php'; //Llama a la configuración del Token

if(isset($_POST['id'])){ //Verificamos que nos estén envíando datos

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $token = $_POST['token'];

    $token_tmp = hash_hmac('sha1', $id, KEY_TOKEN);

    if ($token == $token_tmp) {
        
        if (isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos'][$id])) {
            $_SESSION['carrito']['productos'][$id] += 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['carrito']['productos'][$id] = 1; //producto 1 = 1 cantidad
        }

        $datos['numero'] = count($_SESSION['carrito']['productos']);
        $datos['ok'] = true;

    } else {
        $datos['ok'] = false; 
    }
} else {
    $datos['ok'] = false; 
}

echo json_encode($datos);
```

Y aquí el JS donde se mandan los datos mediante un POST

```
function addProducto(id, token){
  let url = 'clases/carrito.php' //AJAX
  let formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('id', id)
  formData.append('token', token)

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: FormData,
    mode: 'cors'
  }).then(response => response.json()) //Aqui regresa el resultado
  .then(data => {
    if(data.ok){
      let elemento = document.getElementById("num_cart")
      elemento.innerHTML = data.numero
    }
  })
}
```

Este es el config.php

```
<?php

define("KEY_TOKEN", "SMILES123");
define("MONEDA", "$");

//Se inicia la session de PHP

session_start();

$num_cart = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos'])){
    $num_cart = count($_SESSION['carrito']['productos']);
}

?>
```

Comment: Si estás inicializando la sesión antes de ejecutar todo este código?

Comment: Sí, en mi config.php tengo el session_start();

Comment: y esta condicion si se cumple? `$token == $token_tmp`?

Comment: Quiero suponer que sí, revisé el DevTool para saber si había algún problema pero no me identificó ninguno

Comment: puedes intentar poner un `die("la condicion se cumple");"` dentro del `if` de PHP y probar si el mensaje te sale en el request desde el navegador

Comment: Podrías mostrar el contenido de config.php?

Comment: Listo, añadí el config.php a la publicación